# Cypress component testing does not work with composables VueUse - "ref is not defined"

Tags: vue.js, testing, cypress, vuejs3

For some reason [VueUse](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse) is breaking my tests in [Cypress component testing](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/getting-start-with-cypress-component-testing-vue-2-3/). No matter what composable I use, it will throw errors
`> ref is not defined` or `> watch is not defined`. I checked sources and notice that vueuse uses [vue-demi](https://github.com/vueuse/vue-demi) under hood, and all problems are related with imports from vue-demi. But I tried to import something from vue-demi alone, and it works, so I'm confused why it crashes with vueuse.

My setup Vue 3 + Vite.
Reproduction: https://github.com/chojnicki/vitesse Vitesse starter template already has Vue3/Vite and VueUse, so I just added Cypress and same error appears after running `yarn cypress run-ct`

I tired to make this live on codesandbox, but Cypress does not work there due to missing system libraries.

Is this a bug or I'm missing something here?

Log:

```
 at Object.ref (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/node_modules/.vite/@vueuse_core.js?v=9e0ceea7:94:17)
    at useMediaQuery (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/node_modules/.vite/@vueuse_core.js?v=9e0ceea7:1152:41)
    at usePreferredDark (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/node_modules/.vite/@vueuse_core.js?v=9e0ceea7:1379:11)
    at useDark (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/node_modules/.vite/@vueuse_core.js?v=9e0ceea7:1383:26)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/src/logic/dark.ts:2:24)
From previous event:
    at Object.runScripts (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159792:22)
    at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:149271:19)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:35783/__cypress/src/@fs//home/chojnicki/vitesse/node_modules/@cypress/vite-dev-server/client/initCypressTests.js:22:18)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs here:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction#Experimental

vitesse support is missing